# Does the C++ std::binary_search() and then std::lower_bound() combo mean I am doing a binary search twice?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, binary-search

In my search for finding an element quickly in a vector using binary search, I found the std::binary_search function but then realized it only returns a bool, much to my dismay.

But then I found the most common solution to finding an element this way is to pair binary_search() with lower_bound(). After looking at it closer, I think that lower_bound() also searches for the element using a binary search esque situation. So, doesn't that mean I am searching for it twice?

This is an example of what I am referring to:
    std::vector haystack{ 1, 3, 4, 5, 9 };
    int needle = 5;

```
if (std::binary_search(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle)) {
    std::cout << "Found " << needle << '\n';

    std::vector<int>::iterator it = lower_bound(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle);

    int result = *it;

    cout << "Result " << result << endl;
}
```

Am I just doing this the wrong way? Is there another way I can binary search for something within a vector and get the actual found element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are doing two binary searches. Just use `lower_bound` once with an extra comparison:

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle);
if (it != haystack.end() && *it == needle) {
    // found it, here.
}
```

But only do that if you need the iterator. If you just want to check for the existence of `needle`, I would use `std::binary_search()` for added clarity for your users. Which could very well be implemented in terms of `lower_bound` to begin with. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
bool binary_search(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    first = std::lower_bound(first, last, value);
    return (!(first == last) && !(value < *first));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is doing duplicate work.  You can use `std::lower_bound` even if you're not sure whether the element is in the collection or not; if it isn't, it'll return the end iterator.  You can therefore use the following:

```
auto it = lower_bound(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle);
if (it != haystack.end() && *it == needle) {
    cout << "Found " << needle << '\n';
    cout << "Result " << *it << '\n';
}
```

Suppose `needle` is in the haystack.  Then certainly `needle` will be the first element that is not less than `needle`, and so you will find it.

If `needle` is not in the haystack, and all elements are less than `needle`, then the end iterator will be returned and the `it != haystack.end()` check will fail.

If there is an element less than `needle` then an iterator `it` to it will be returned, but the check `*it == needle` will fail.

Either way, you get the desired result.